# How can I port entire VS Code project developed in C/C++ on Linux to WIndows?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cmake, makefile, nrf52

I have a working project in Linux and I have successfully flashed the code on to a nRF5480-DK controller. Now I am trying to do the same on windows.I have installed all the tools as recommended in the documentation https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fug_nrf_cltools%2FUG%2Fcltools%2Fnrf_installation.html.

The project structure is

```
-  build
- .vscode
  - c_cpp_properties.json
  - launch.json
  - settings.json
  - tasks.json
- include
   - *.h
- src
  - *.c
- linked.ld
- Makefile
```

I have installed the compiler and sdk files and have given the path in `settings.json` file.

```
{
    "sdkRoot": "/nRF5_SDK_17.1.0_ddde560/nRF5_SDK_17.1.0_ddde560",
    "gnuInstallRoot": "/GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain/102021/bin/",
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Enabled"
}
```

What changes should I make to the project structure? Should I replace Makefile with CMake?
Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: If you are using VSCode on windows, I don't think any changes in the project structure are needed. Specific settings - maybe. But you better create a new project, set it up and  and import source files only.

Comment: `Should I replace Makefile with CMake`  *Make* is just one of the generator options for CMake. You may want to make your project CMake compatible under Linux first, and theoretically, that should be enough to generate (with whatever generator) the same project on Windows

Comment: When I try to build it, it gives me the following error : `/usr/bin/sh: -c: Zeile 0: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort `('´ . I dont know from where is it accessing /usr/bin/sh path.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I _think_ OP has a `Makefile` but _not_ Cmake files. That is, the Makefile is _not_ generated from cmake. OP would have to convert to cmake to be able to generate windows specific build files?

Comment: _Side note:_ [Ubuntu] linux is the de facto standard for arm cross development. You've already got that working. Why do you want to make your life more difficult by using a more problematic solution (not just installation but going forward)?

Comment: @CraigEstey *linux is the de facto standard for arm cross development* - well.. a company I work in  (a major CPU manufacturer) isn't aware of this :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. nVidia (for their Jetson platform) thinks that it is ;-) As does Xilinx

Comment: @CraigEstey Xilinx is a part of a *major CPU manufacturer* now.. Just saying :)  Anyway, the same tools that are available for Linux cross-development are available for Windows. So it is just a personal preference.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Personal experience (business). I've used the same tools on both platforms at a given company and the linux tools always worked better. And only 30% of the companies even used windows at all

Comment: I am told to make it work on both platform, hence.As told in the comments, I only have a Makefile and not CMake.